# Code style - "flattening" a package's namespace

Tags: python, coding-style, namespaces, flatten

My package hierarchy:

```
InstrumentController/
    __init__.py
    instruments/
        __init__.py
        _BaseInstrument.py
        Keithley2000.py
        # etc...
```

The contents of the instrument files:

```
# _BaseInstrument.py
class _BaseInstrument(object):
    """Base class for instruments"""
    # etc...

# Keithley2000.py
from InstrumentController.instruments._BaseInstrument import _BaseInstrument
class Keithley2000(_BaseInstrument):
    # etc...
```

I want my users to be able to access the classes without having to delve into a hierarchy of modules. They should just have to type `from InstrumentController.instruments import Keithley2000`, not `from InstrumentController.instruments.Keithley2000 import Keithley2000`.

For this purpose I have a bunch of lines like this in `InstrumentController.instruments.__init__`:

```
from .Keithley2000 import Keithley2000
from .StanfordSR830 import StanfordSR830
# etc...
```

So now the classes sit at the *top* of the package's namespace, rather than in submodules. My question is: is this a good idea? The classes have the same name as the modules to which they belong, so importing the class at the top level renders the module unavailable. This makes me a little squeamish - is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Putting the classes in a single module is not an option. People will be writing new ones to go into the package in the future and I don't want them modifying existing files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How you are doing it is acceptable, but I recommend that you recase all package/module names to lowercase as 1) that is the convention [specified in PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#package-and-module-names), and 2) it will remove your shadowing issue.

Comment: PEP8 says that functions should also have all-lowercase names. What naming convention is recommended to resolve the case where I need to `import` a function from a submodule of the same name?

Comment: The normal fix for that is to not have functions with the same name as the module (which is not such a terrible thing since names of both modules and functions should reflect purpose and not ownership).