# How can I flatten the namespace of just one module?

Tags: python, import, structure, package, importerror

I have the following simple project and package structure:

```
Project/
    package/
        __init__.py
        a.py
            class One: ...
            class Two: ...
        b.py
            from . import a
            class Three: ...
            class Four: ...
```

I want users to be able to use it as such:

```
import package
# or
from package import Three, Four
from package.a import One, Two
# or
from package import a
```

I've tried several uses of `from...import` in the `__init__.py` but to no avail! Here's a summary of what I've tried to put in `Project/package/__init__.py` and the errors they produced when attempting to `import package`:

```
from .b import Three, Four
#  ImportError: No module named 'package.b'  
---
from b import Three, Four
#  ImportError: No module named 'b'
---
from package.b import Three, Four
# ImportError: cannot import name Three
```

I thought I had already solved this problem in my last project... (see: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23726194/3109193))

**TL;DR**
What do I need to put in `Project/package/__init__.py` such that users can then import classes Three and Four directly from my package without needing to know in which module they exist? In other words, *how can I flatten the namespace of module `b`?*

Edit: using Python 3.3, but I may switch to 3.4 and I may also need to support 2.7.

Edit: added a TL;DR

Edit: significantly reformatted the question for clarity

Edit: updated title to reflect the clarity :)

Edit: added reference to a similar (solved) question that doesn't seem to work in this case

Comment: You might have circular imports. Do you have any imports in `a.py`?

Comment: No, all imports are as above :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Code style - "flattening" a package's namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12626336/code-style-flattening-a-packages-namespace)

Answer (score 0):

You don't use the dot: it's as simple as that.

In b.py:

```
from a import Three, Four
```

It seems that your program is looking for a `package.b`, not just b. This probably means that using a . won't work

Output from `from .a import`

```
File "/storage/emulated/0/com.hipipal.qpyplus/scripts3/.last_tmp.py",   line 1, in <module>
from .a import One, Two
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package
```

Output from `from a import` (expected)

```
1
2
```

Comment: And what if there is a package called `a`?

Comment: @rhgrant10 You'll have to rename your file

Comment: @rhgrant Which version of Python are you using?

Comment: Updated the question to indicate Python version :-)

Comment: @rhgrant From experimentation, by renaming a to time, I've found that Python favours the local scripts over the installed packages.

Comment: Well I'm not getting a ValueError, I'm getting an ImportError.

Comment: I think you may not have an `__init__.py` file in that directory which is causing the `ValueError`. That is a very different error despite being caused by the same syntax.

Comment: @rhgrant10 Ahh yes. Is your __init__.py empty?

Comment: That's the question: what do I need to put in it such that users can then import classes Three and Four directly from my package without needing to know in which module they exist.

Comment: I just tried `from b import Three, Four` and it produced another `ImportError`:

    ImportError: No module named 'b'